# Proof Taylor's theorem: "Let $M$ be the unique solution"; is this always possible?

Tags: taylor-expansion, proof-explanation

I have a question concerning the proof of the following theorem:

[image]

I don't see how they can state that we're looking for a unique solution $M$;
$$
f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{f^{(k)}(c)}{k!}(x-c)^k+\frac{M(x-c)^n}{n!}.
$$
How do we know the solution is unique? How do we know it exists at all?
I'm a little bit confused by this. Why don't they word it like this: we are looking for a solution $M$, and we're hoping that it exists and is unique.

Comment: The proof is confusing, yes. Take a look to [these other proofs](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_Theorem/One_Variable), or just search for a proof from a different book of analysis. [These](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/481661/simplest-proof-of-taylors-theorem#492165) other proofs are useful too.