# Proving Taylor's Theorem On Two Vriables

Tags: taylor-expansion

apologies beforehand if I still lack the pertinent "mathematical" language. I'm a law major having only recently switched to maths, and as much as it's embarrassing to admit, I'm very, very new to anything beyond high-school mathematics.

I'm reading Riley's book, and, in section 5.7, there is a formula for two-variable Taylor series, namely:

$$f(x,y) = f(x_0,y_0) + f_x\Delta{x} + f_y\Delta{y} + \frac{1}{2}f_{xx}(\Delta{x})^2 + f_{xy}\Delta{x}\Delta{y} + \frac{1}{2}f_{yy}(\Delta{y})^2 + ...$$

I've been trying to prove Taylor's theorem "my own way"; first I set:

$$f(x,y) \approx f(x_0,y_0) + \int_{x_0}^{x}\!f_x(x,y)\mathrm{d}x  +\int_{y_0}^{y}\!f_y(x,y)\mathrm{d}y $$

then set:

$$f_x(x,y) \approx f_x(x_0,y_0) + \int_{x_0}^{x}\!f_{xx}(x,y)\mathrm{d}x  +\int_{y_0}^{y}\!f_{xy}(x,y)\mathrm{d}y $$

along with:

$$f_y(x,y) \approx f_y(x_0,y_0) + \int_{x_0}^{x}\!f_{xy}(x,y)\mathrm{d}x  +\int_{y_0}^{y}\!f_{yy}(x,y)\mathrm{d}y $$

now the two previous formulas for $f_x$ and $f_y$, when replaced in the original formula for $f$, would yield:

$$f(x,y) \approx f(x_0,y_0) + \\
\int_{x_0}^{x}\![f_x(x_0,y_0) + \int_{x_0}^{x}\!f_{xx}(x,y)\mathrm{d}x  +\int_{y_0}^{y}\!f_{xy}(x,y)\mathrm{d}y]\mathrm{d}x + \\
\int_{y_0}^{y}\![f_y(x_0,y_0) + \int_{x_0}^{x}\!f_{xy}(x,y)\mathrm{d}x  +\int_{y_0}^{y}\!f_{yy}(x,y)\mathrm{d}y]\mathrm{d}y $$

taking $f(x_0,y_0)$, $f_x(x_0,y_0)$, and $f_y(x_0,y_0)$, respectively, equal to $f(x,y)$, $f_x(x,y)$, and $f_y(x,y)$ in the vicinity of $(x_0,y_0)$, and simplifying further, gives:

$$f(x,y) \approx f(x_0,y_0) + f_x(x,y)\Delta(x) + f_y(x,y)\Delta{y} + \frac{1}{2}f_{xx}(x,y)(\Delta{x})^2 + 2f_{xy}(x,y)\Delta{x}\Delta{y} + \frac{1}{2}f_{yy}(x,y)(\Delta{y})^2$$

which, while very much close to the actual formula, has got an extra $f_{xy}(x,y)\Delta{x}\Delta{y}$ in it; I have been struggling to find out what exactly I have missed during the process but I have not made it anywhere; not yet, at least.

Could I ask what exactly I'm doing wrong? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure that you are doing anything wrong.  You have perhaps underestimated the difficulty of proving (indeed, verifying) Taylor's theorem.  You tried to achieve the first few terms of an infinite series by applying two first order approximations in succession.  It didn't work out.  It shouldn't be too much of a surprise.  You might find this link interesting: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/481661/simplest-proof-of-taylors-theorem

Comment: As I see it you wrote $\int_{x_0}^{x}\![\int_{x_0}^{x}\!f_{xx}(x,y)\mathrm{d}x]\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{2}f_{xx}(x,y)(\Delta{x})^2$ and $\int_{x_0}^{x}\![\int_{x_0}^{x}\!f_{xy}(x,y)\mathrm{d}y]\mathrm{d}x=f_{xy}(x,y)\Delta{y}\Delta{x}$ so it seems to me you're missing a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ in the second expression and that should fix the difference