# Proving statement regarding

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I have to prove the following statement:

> $f$ is twice differentiable on $[a, a+h]$. Prove that there exists $c \in (a, a+h)$ such that
> $$f(a+h)=f(a)+hf'(a)+\frac{1}{2}h^2f''(c)$$

I need to solve this problem without using Taylor's theorem, L'Hopital's rule, or any higher order of thinking. The things that I can use is the mean value theorem, Cauchy's MVT, and definition of differentiation. I tried to mimic the proof for the Lagrange form of Taylor's Theorem that uses Cauchy's MVT, given in this page.[(Wikipedia_Page)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Derivation_for_the_mean_value_forms_of_the_remainder)
Also I tried to apply the MVT twice, but it did not give me the exact form, instead the term $h(b-a)f''(c)$. I tried to view the RHS as a quadratic polynomial about $h$, and tried to use IVT for the cases where $c=a$ and $c=a+h$. All did not give me a satisfactory proof.

How can I get the required result? Are any of my approaches able to lead to the proof?

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/481661/42969

Comment: Or this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Derivation_for_the_mean_value_forms_of_the_remainder

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for the link. Actually the second link was the same page in my post. I'll give it another try. I am now pretty sure that the proof of Taylor's Theorem at $k=1$ is the case I'm looking for.

Comment: The Wikipedia page shows a proof using Cauchy's mean value theorem.

Comment: @MartinR Yes indeed. Thanks to your help, I solved the problem. Thanks a lot sir.